# How to use openpyxl to insert one sheet to a template?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to generate excel spreadsheets by python, the first few tabs are exactly same, all are refer to the last page, so how to insert the last page by openpyxl? because the first few tabs are too complex so load_workbook is always failed, is there have any other way to insert tabs without loading?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, openpyxl does not allow you to access only one cell, or a limited number of cells for that matter. In order to access any information in a given worksheet, openpyxl will create one in the memory. This is the reason for which you will be unable to add a Sheet without opening the entire document in memory and overwriting it at the end.